# Interactive application to aggregate and visualise data: is pandas+plotting library the right tool?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, visualization, data-cube

Consider this example. I have a pandas data frame with  three "dimensions": day, location, item id, and some values, let's say sales and demand.

I would like to aggregate sales and compute and visualise statistics over either dimensions. For example, I can aggregate over item and compute for each day and location the total sales and the sales ratio over the total. I could also have more "creative" kpis to compute, so I should also be able to compute generic functions over aggregations.

There are several possible aggregations I could make. I could aggregate over location, day or item, or over two dimensions at time: location and day, location and item ...
I could have many aggregations to consider as I have to verify with the users how something , in this example "sales", is behaving, and we need to explore several dimensions, at least in this phase of software development.

I did this with pandas and plotnine.
I created the corresponding aggregations as data frames via pandas and then plotted them.

Then, I would like my charts to be interactive and easy to use for the user.

Perhaps I could get something by using pandas and plotly. I need to check how compatible plotly is with plotnine

However, I wonder if this does not look more like a BI application. Or, in any case, if there is a library or software that would allow to achieve the same result while specifying less code, that needs to be maintained in our already large code base.

What other options do you think I should evaluate?

TIA